# Forbid to add rows with a specific foreign key in SQL (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, check-constraints

I have two append-only tables, one of which has a foreign key to another.

For the purpose of this question, I'll call them `sets` and `items`.

`sets` has an unique id.

`items` has a unique id and a foreign key to `sets.id`.

How I work with these tables in code is that in a transaction, I create a `sets` row and several `items` rows that reference this `sets` row.

After this initial operation, I'd like to make it impossible to write any more `items` rows that would refer to that `sets` row, preferably on the database level with triggers, constraints, or other means to achieve that. In that sense, the `sets` row is closed for accepting any more `items`.

Is there a way to achieve what I envision here with Postgres?

And secondly, is this even a good practice to do that on database level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you looking for by:

1. Add a boolean column to `sets` table indicating that the set accepts additional referencing items or not. Default value to True (will accept items).
2. Create an insert trigger on `items` that checks the related `sets`
   If the set does not accept additional items then raise an exception.
3. Create an update trigger on `sets` that does not allow changing the
   column in #1 above from false to true.

Now create a process which inserts into `sets` with flag = true (default). Then insert the related `items`. Finally set the flag = false.  This creates the `sets` and `items` tables but will not allow additional related items for the set. It still leaves the ability to add items to a specific set until fie flag is set. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/32HFj2fz)).

So *is this even a good practice*? Basically that is unanswerable without the specifics of how and when it will be used. (IMHO) Generally, for an original entry transactional system, it is a poor practice. Errors and omissions happen all the time, this process does not allow for them. It requires perfection that does not happen in the real world. On the held for an system generated archive it probably is a good practice (may not even be restrictive enough).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. It helped me a lot. For my case, I think it'll be "good enough" to implement that because we don't allow omissions to "sets" by design (it's a ledger). Any omissions facts are new entries and are first-class citizens in the system.

Comment: Actually, it's also going to be flag = false by default (and = true at the end), seems to convey the intent better in my case (closed=true) vs (opened=false)